# Why does Condemned only have 970 unlockable achievement points?

Tags: achievements, condemned

I just finished playing through the first **Condemned** game on the Xbox 360 and was hoping to go back and max out the achievements. I noticed that for some reason it only has a total of 970 points rather than the normal 1000 for games released on a disk. What is the reason for this? Was this before Microsoft had achievement standards? Were there achievements removed at some point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the story I heard on a podcast was that since Condemned was an early Xbox 360 title, the developers weren't really sure how achievements would be used in practice quite yet, so they didn't use all the points. Some charming forum posters have a similar conclusion over [here](http://www.achieve360points.com/forums/showthread.php?s=3c18ebe5f087c9e012e3b4439bf9d38f&t=107055), but I can't find a more direct source.

However, lots of early 360 games have weird achievement setups ([NBA 2k6, for one](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/nba-2k6/achievements/)) compared to what we're used to today, so it seems reasonable that's the case here.

Comment: Seems like as good an answer as any.